# Android checking multiple checkboxes

Tags: android, checkbox

```
       for(int i=3;i<plates1.length();++i)
        {
            final CheckBox cb=new CheckBox(this);

            JSONObject jObj1 = plates1.getJSONObject(i);
            String date=jObj1.getString("Name");
            cb.setText(date);
            cb.setId(i);
         }
```

I have my for loop here. I have created checkboxes using the for loop but I am not able to figure out the logic on how I should select two checkboxes at a time making use of the checkbox ID. Could you please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i=3;i<plates1.length();++i)
        {
            final CheckBox cb=new CheckBox(this);

            JSONObject jObj1 = plates1.getJSONObject(i);
            String date=jObj1.getString("Name");
            cb.setText(date);
            cb.setId(i);
            parentView.addView(cb) // you should add it in parent layout
         }
```

an then this is how you access it..

```
((CheckBox)parentView.findViewById(3)).setChecked(true) // i took the first check box added

// do the same with others
```

Comment: thank you sandy but how do I assign this to a variable? I am planning to use if loop and when I select two checkboxes I am going to add some activity